# Rest api work on emulator and bad request error on real device

Tags: php, android, rest, web-services, android-volley

I use a rest web service on my host .
I use it with volley library in my project and run my project on android emulator and it works correct (means argument send and receive correct message)
I use `$_GET` method and my link is like this :

```
https://example.com/myapi.php?arg1=val1&arg2=val2
```

but this web service does not work on real device and I receive from my host:

> error 400 bad request

I use this method on my request and it did not work for me :

```java
{
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("arg1",val1);
        params.put("arg2",val2);
        return params;
    }
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: print your url at the time of calling . see is it both same

Comment: i say my app is work correct on emulator so the calling url is right

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your ip address `https://example.com` to `https://yourComputerIpAddress`

Good luck.

Comment: i use an online host not a localhost like xampp

Comment: can you share more details like full message error or something that can help us find the bug ?

Comment: i receive this in logcat :E/Volley: [8265] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://example.com/myapi.php?arg1=bXJiMDA5OEB5YWhvby5jb20=&arg2=MDkxMzA5MDM1NTA=